# Prove that if the normal subgroup H and the quotient group $G / H$ of $G$ are periodic, then the group $G$ itself is periodic.

Tags: group-theory

A group is called periodic if each of its elements
has a finite order. Prove that if the normal subgroup $H$ and the quotient group $G / H$ of $G$ are periodic, then the group $G$ itself is periodic.

Answer (score 3):

For all $x\in G$ there is some $n$ such that $x^n\in H$. Therefore, there is some $m$ such that $(x^n)^m=x^{mn}=e$.

Comment: oh, and that is all solution, impressive,thanks